# JQuery plug-in conflict - combine scripts without conflict?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I've searched high & low for a solution to this but can't figure it out. I'm a javascript noob so I apologize in advance for my ignorance. I really appreciate any help you can give.

Anyway, I have two jquery plug-ins running on a page. One is Isotope and the other is Fancybox. They both work fine separately but together, when images are clicked and Fancybox activates, the images don't autosize to fit the screen. Everything else about the plug-ins works fine.

I have these .js scripts linked to:

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js
/js/jquery.isotope.js
/js/jquery.fancybox.js
/js/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js
/js/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js
```

And then this script following it in the document:

```
$(function(){

  var $container = $('#container');

  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.project'
  });

});

$(".fancybox")
.attr('rel', 'gallery')
.fancybox({
    padding : 0 ,
    minWidth : 215 ,
    maxWidth : 900 ,
    autoSize : true ,
});
```

I've tried various methods like no.conflict but either I'm doing it wrong or it doesn't work. If anyone can give some advice on how to separate these scripts, I'd be immensely grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors?

Comment: No, I'm using Dreamweaver and it's not coming up with any errors, so I think syntax, etc. is ok.

Comment: The javascript errors would appear in the browser that you are using to run your website.

Comment: Sorry, thanks for commenting. Here's the site: http://www.ed-hatrick-smith.com/work/projects/wardrobe-world.php     No errors

Comment: I cannot see anything wrong. The images are opening up at their maximum size. Fancybox doesn't stretch the images as far as I am aware, it only displays them at their "natural" size

Comment: Please check here: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples Maybe it's new feature. They resize just fine when I don't have the Isotope script running also.

Comment: Have found a fix but it won't let me post for 8 hours cause I'm a newbie :P  Will upload it then. Thanks Tim for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found a fix. It's a bit odd but... whatever.

I have separated the in-document script into two separate scripts and also moved the linked .js files above each script. I have then added a separate call to the jquery library for each. So there are now two calls to jquery. It looks like this:

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js
/js/jquery.fancybox.js
/js/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js
/js/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js

$(".fancybox")
     .attr('rel', 'gallery')
     .fancybox({
        padding : 0 ,
        minWidth : 215 ,
        maxWidth : 900 ,
        autoSize : true ,
     });

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js
/js/jquery.isotope.js

$(function(){
   var $container = $('#container');
      $container.isotope({
      itemSelector: '.project'
  });    
});
```

I'm sure it's not ideal but it works so I don't care too much. Thanks Tim B James for helping.